# npx create-react-app test somehow gives webpack error

Tags: reactjs, webpack, npx

so I don't remember updating anything, but npx stopped working for me today!
other older react projects still working (npm start). So when I'm creating new react project:

```
npx create-react-app test
cd test
npm start
```

I got this webpack **error**:

```
Failed to compile.
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module.rules[2].oneOf[1].include: The provided value "/home/coding/!convr/test/src" contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the test@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in log:
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

PS: sorry for making it that long, but I need to figure it out

Comment: Perhaps your directory's name ```"/home/coding/!convr/test/src"``` contains the literal string "!", which isn't allowed. Try testing it on another directory

Comment: ... `contains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it` ...